# Inner join with sub query to filter record from pivot table

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query

```
 SELECT t.*
 FROM `User` `t`
 INNER JOIN (
     SELECT cv.relatedId
     FROM CustomValue cv
     WHERE (cv.customFieldId=11 AND (cv.fieldValue like '%dsasda%')) OR (cv.customFieldId=15 AND (cv.fieldValue like '%1%'))
     GROUP BY cv.relatedId
     HAVING count(*) >= 1
) tblcv  ON  tblcv.relatedId = t.id
```

I need to do add a AND CONDITION. i am wondering how to.

This is the data set.

[image]

As circled in blue, I need to compare against both records for a particular `relatedId`.

For example, for related id 4031 I need to check if `customFieldId` = 11 and `fieldValue` like `%dsasda%` and if `customFieldId` = 15 and `fieldValue` like '%1%'

So the result of query for this data set should have `4031` `relatedId` as an answer but I get all 3 related id result. it seems to be using OR CONDITION.

[image]

When try to use AND condition. i dont get any results. This is with AND condition.

```
SELECT cv.relatedId
FROM CustomValue cv
WHERE (cv.customFieldId=11 AND (cv.fieldValue like '%dsasda%')) AND (cv.customFieldId=15 AND (cv.fieldValue like '%1%'))
GROUP BY cv.relatedId
HAVING count(*) >= 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match both conditions then you need to match at least 2 rows in your having

```
HAVING count(*) >= 1
                 ^ remove equality operator
```

You're getting back the 2 other id's because they each match 1 row (you've circled them).

If `(relatedId,fieldValue)` is not unique, then use `distinct` to make sure each group has both values.

```
HAVING count(distinct fieldValue) > 1
```